# Is there a python or pandas function to cut a list into groups that are equal sized or as symmetric as possible?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like a function that functions like `pandas.qcut` however, gives me as 'balanced' or 'symmetric' splits as possible.

At the moment, if I use:

```
pd.qcut(range(1, 11), 3, labels=False, duplicates="drop")
```

I get:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
```

But I would like the middle group to have four entries instead i.e.:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64).
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer arithmetic will do it.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([i%3 for i in range(1, 11)]).sort_values().values
```

#### output

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```